# How to specify a server when connected to multiple severs and running a command in WeeChat?

Tags: irc, weechat

Sometimes I connect to 2 IRC servers in WeeChat: first connect to “Freenode” and then “otw.”

WeeChat seems to consider all my commands to be related to server “otw.”

Is there any way I can specify the server when running a command?

This is what the buffer list looks like, and I don't know how to send commands to the Freenode buffer

[image: buffer list]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://weechat.org/files/doc/devel/weechat_quickstart.en.html#connect_to_irc_server):

> By default, server buffers are merged with WeeChat core buffer. To switch between the core buffer and server buffers, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.
>
> It is possible to disable auto merge of server buffers to have independent server buffers:
>
> ```
> /set irc.look.server_buffer independent
> ```